# My website is responsive everywhere BUT when resizing browser window

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I don't know why but both in dev tools and on mobile device my website is responsive, however when I resize the browser window it doesn't hit the breakpoint, and the portfolio grid doesn't switch from 3 columns to 1. This is an issue for me because it is my portfolio site I'll be sending to employers and I know they like to resize the window to check for responsiveness. Thank you in advance for advice.

```css
        /*Globals*/
        
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hachi+Maru+Pop&display=swap');
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Hachi Maru Pop', monospace;
        }
        
        body {
            line-height: 1.6;
        }
        
        .container {
            max-width: 1100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 40px;
        }
        
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        img {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }
        
        .greeting {
            margin-top: 60px;
            font-size: 35px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        
        p {
            margin: 15px auto 0px auto;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        /* Repeating Styles*/
        
        .greeting,
        #about,
        #portfolio,
        #contact {
            text-align: center;
        }

        p,
        .contact-form {
            width: 80%;
        }
        
        .navbar,
        #portfolio,
        .social-footer {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #ee7f7e, #f896fc, #b189f5, #87c1f1, #8ee3ee, #8cf391, #f1fa90, #f3cb8a, #f5a289);
        }
        
        span,
        .greeting,
        #contact,
        .contact-form,
        input,
        .message,
       .contact-form button,
       .menu-options li {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #ee7f7e, #f896fc, #b189f5, #87c1f1, #8ee3ee, #8cf391, #f1fa90, #f3cb8a, #f5a289);
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -moz-background-clip: text;
            -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -o-background-clip: text;
            -o-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -ms-background-clip: text;
            -ms-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
        
        .marquee,
       .contact-form button,
        .modal {
            border: 2px solid;
            border-image: conic-gradient(#ee7f7e, #f896fc, #b189f5, #87c1f1, #8ee3ee, #8cf391, #f1fa90, #f3cb8a, #ee7f7e) 1
        }
        
        ul,
        .navbar,
        .socials,
        .modal-bg,
        .modal{
            display: flex;
        }
        
        
        .contact-form input,
        .contact-form textarea,
        .contact-form button,
        .modal-bg {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .navbar,
        .navbar a,
        #portfolio {
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        .contact-form label,
        .marquee span {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .project img,
        .portfolio-btn {
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .contact-form input,
        .contact-form textarea,
        .contact-form button {
            padding: 12px 20px;
            outline: none;
        }
        
        .contact-form input,
        .contact-form textarea{
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
            border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ee7f7e 0%, #f896fc 25%, #8ee3ee 50%, #f1fa90 75%, #f5a289 100%);
            border-image-slice: 1;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        
        .contact-form input:focus,
        .contact-form textarea:focus {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
        }
        
        .modal-bg,
        .modal {
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .greeting,
        .headshot,
        .marquee span,
        .marquee {
            position: relative;
        }

        /* Navbar*/
        .navbar{
            height: 40px;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        
        .navbar img {
            margin: 10px;
        }
        
        #menu-button {
            display: none;
            margin: auto;
            background-color : transparent;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
        }

        .sections {
            margin-right: 1vh;
        }
        
        .sections li {
            margin: auto 2vh;
        }
        
        .seperation {
            padding: 0 1em;
            border-width: 0 1px;
            border-style: solid;
        }
        
        .navbar a:hover {
            color: #000000;
            border-bottom: solid #000000 1px;
        }
/* Drop down menu */
.menu-options {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-link{
    display: initial;
    
}
.page-link li {
    margin: 50px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.social-link{
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 40px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top:40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: menu-container 1s linear;
}
.noMenu {
    display: none;
}

@keyframes menu-container {
    0% {
        top: -90%;
    }
}
        /*Marquee Scroller*/
        
        .marquee {
            width: 600px;
            height: 175px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 5% auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .marquee span {
            top: 15%;
            left: 100%;
            animation: marquee 8.5s linear infinite;
        }
        
        .marquee:hover span {
            animation-play-state: paused;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(1) {
            animation-delay: 0s;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(2) {
            animation-delay: 0.4s;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(3) {
            animation-delay: 0.8s;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(4) {
            animation-delay: 1.2s;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(5) {
            animation-delay: 1.6s;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(6) {
            animation-delay: 2.0s;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(7) {
            animation-delay: 2.4s;
        }
        
        .marquee span:nth-child(8) {
            animation-delay: 2.75s;
        }
        
        @keyframes marquee {
            0% {
                left: 95%;
            }
            100% {
                left: -170%;
            }
        }
        /* Portfolio Section */
        
        #portfolio {
            padding-bottom: 5em;
        }
        
        #portfolio-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-auto-rows: minmax(100, auto);
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.329);
        }
    
        .portfolio-btn {
            outline: none;
            padding: 2%;
            margin: 5px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: transparent;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        /* Contact Section */
        #contact {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .contact-form {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        
        .contact-form label {
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 5%;
        }
        
        .contact-form button {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
        
        @media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
            .contact-form {
                width: 60%;
            }
        }
        
        @media all and (min-width: 1080px) {
            .contact-form {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
        
        /*Footer*/
        .footer {
            display: none;
        }
        
        /* Modal */
        
        .modal-bg {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            align-items: center;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: visibility 0s opacity 0.5s;
        }
        
        .modal-active {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .modal {
            width: 30%;
            height: 30%;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.582);
        }

        .modal h1 {
            margin: auto;
        }
        /* Media Queries*/
        /*Phone*/
        /* Portrait */
        
        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) and (orientation: portrait) {
            
            /* Navbar*/
            .navbar {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 2;
            }
            #menu-button{
                display: initial;
            }
            .menu-container{
            background: #474747ea;
            
            }
            .menu-options {
                display: initial;
            }
            .navbar img {
                margin: 0;
            }
            .socials {
                display: none;
            }
            .sections {
                display: none;
            }
            

            /* About Section */
            #about {
                margin-top: 10%;
            }

            .greeting {
                padding: 0 20px;
            }
    
        /*Marquee Scroller*/
        
        .marquee {
            bottom: initial;
            left: initial;
            width: 300px;
            height: 175px;
        }
        
        .marquee span {
            animation: marquee 9s linear infinite;
        }
        
        @keyframes marquee {
            0% {
                left: 200%;
            }
            100% {
                left: -340%;
            }
        }
        /* Portfolio Section */
        
        #portfolio-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: initial;
            grid-auto-rows: initial;
        }
        
        .project {
            margin: 1em;
        }

        /*footer*/

        .footer {
            display: initial;
        }
        .social-footer {
            height: 40px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        /* Modal */
        
        .modal {
            width: 70%;
            height: 30%;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }


        /* Landscape */
        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 900px){
            
           /* Portfolio Section */
        
        #portfolio-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: initial;
            grid-auto-rows: initial;
        }
        
        .project {
            margin: 1em;
        }
          /*Marquee Scroller*/
        
          .marquee {
            bottom: initial;
            left: initial;
            width: 300px;
            height: 175px;
        }
        
        .marquee span {
            animation: marquee 9s linear infinite;
        }
        
        @keyframes marquee {
            0% {
                left: 200%;
            }
            100% {
                left: -340%;
            }
        }

        /* Modal */
        
        .modal-bg {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            align-items: center;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: visibility 0s opacity 0.5s;
        }
        
        .modal-active {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .modal {
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <title>CV</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!--Nav-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <!-- Mobile view-->
        <button id="menu-button" ><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-menu-rounded-25.png" alt=""></button>

<!-- Desktop view-->
        <div class="socials">
            <a href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-instagram-20.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-github-20-2.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-linkedin-20.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="sections">
            <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="seperation">
                <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!--Mobile drop down menu-->
    <div class="noMenu menu-container">
        <div class="menu-options">
            <ul class="page-link">
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-disappear" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-disappear" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-disappear" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="social-link">
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-disappear" href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-instagram-20.png" alt="">instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-disappear" href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-github-20-2.png" alt="">github</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="menu-disappear" href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-linkedin-20.png" alt="">linkedin</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!--About-->
    <div id="about">
            <div class="greeting">Hello, my name is Prima. I'm a front-end web developer.
            </div>

            <img class="headshot" src="/images/my-pixel.gif" alt=" ">

            <div class="marquee">
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-html-5-100.png" alt="HTML5"> HTML5</span>
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-css3-100.png" alt="CSS3">CSS3</span>
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-javascript-logo-100.png" alt="Javascript">Javascript</span>
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-npm-100.png" alt="NPM">Node Package Manager</span>
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-git-100.png" alt="Git Bash">Git</span>
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-webpack-100.png" alt="">Webpack</span>
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-github-100.png" alt="">Github</span>
                <span><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-react-100.png" alt="">React</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--Portfolio-->
    <div id="portfolio">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <div id="portfolio-container">
                <div class="project">
                    <h3>Weather App</h3>
                        <img src="/images/weather.png">
                    <a href="https://simple-weatherapplication.netlify.app/" target="_blan" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button class="portfolio-btn">Preview</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="project">
                    <h3>Portfolio Builder</h3>
                        <img src="/images/cv-maker.png">
                    <a href="https://resumeandcvbuilder.netlify.app/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button class="portfolio-btn">Preview</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="project">
                    <h3>Etch-a-Sketch</h3>
                        <img src="/images/etch-a-sketch.png">
                    <a href="https://my-etch-a-sketch-project.netlify.app/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button class="portfolio-btn">Preview</button></a>
                </div>
                
            </div>
    </div>

    <!--Contact-->

    <div id="contact">
        <h1>Contact me</h1>
        <p>Send a message and I will get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
        <form method="POST" class="contact-form">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="name" required/>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="email" required/>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="message" cols="30 " rows="10" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

<!--Footer on Mobile-->
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="social-footer">
            <a href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-instagram-20.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-github-20-2.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="***" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="/images/Favorites/icons8-linkedin-20.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Modal-->
    <div class="modal-bg">
        <div class="modal">
            <h1 class="message">Message sent!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js "></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-app.js "></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js "></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay so i took a look at your code and i think it because you set all the media queries to only the device width. The height of the browser and the height of the normal phone or dev tools are not the same . so trying doing it for the height

Comment: Please add code when you can. Don't just give suggestion.